# Value of type 'UIbutton' has no more 'titleforState'

Tags: ios, swift

Here is an error I'm getting on swift when I am just trying to put a simple command.

[image: example image]

Answer (score 3):

The syntax has changed:

```
button.title(for: .normal)
```